# Eclipse doesn't offer to add import or show functions for android objects

Tags: android, eclipse, import

Somehow I've screwed up my Eclipse installation. Used to be if I added a new instance of an Android object (say a TextView) and I right clicked on the error, it would offer to add the import. Also if I had an Android object and typed it followed by a period, it would show me all the allowed functions. Now it doesn't do either, just shows me java info. Don't know what I did, since this used to work. I updated everything, but still no joy. Can anyone help me get this back to the way it was?

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

Check your settings in Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->Content Assist